# Can you build craft search for a range?

Tags: search, rangeslider, craftcms

I can see in the searching documentation it explains searching for key words but can't see anything about a range.
Is it possible using craft to do this?
Eg. Time between 5minutes and 5 hours - filter between those and return the results between that

Answer (score 1):

If you define a time range (startDate, endDate), you can query between those ranges. You may have to find which is the correct filter for you (atom, duration, date, date_modify or datetime). I would maybe try the duration filter on the query in this case. Since Craft essentially runs the strtotime PHP function you can setup variables similar to below:

```
{% set startDate = date('-5 hours')|atom %}
{% set endDate = date('-5 minutes')|atom %}

<!-- Your query depends on what your doing. This will get posts. -->
{% set entries = craft.entries().postDate(['and', ">= #{start}", "< #{end}"]).all() %}
```

For more information take a look at Crafts docs they have on filters if you have not already - https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/filters.html#date and https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php or [Explanation of strtotime function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Good Luck!